# coldfusion + xml get node according to date

Tags: xml, coldfusion

XML trickiness. I'm trying to isolate the node with a sports "Match" that is currently in progress or is the next upcoming Match.

thisScheduleXML:

```
<Data>
        <Sport type="Union">
            <Schedules>
                <Competition id="48" name="SR" type="Union" group="">
                    <Match id="1684" round="Week 1" previewArticleID="" matchReportArticleID="" status="Upcoming" alternateId="1">
                        <MatchDate startDateLocal="2011-02-18 19:35:00" dayName="Fri" shortDate="18-Feb">2011-02-18 19:35:00</MatchDate>
                        <Venue id="30" timeZoneID="NZDT" gmtMinutes="780" venue="Westpac Stadium" location="Wellington">Westpac Stadium, Wellington</Venue>
                        <HomeTeam id="8" alternateId="428">Hurricanes</HomeTeam>
                        <AwayTeam id="7" alternateId="427">Highlanders</AwayTeam>
                    </Match>
                    <Match id="1685" round="Week 1" previewArticleID="" matchReportArticleID="" status="Upcoming" alternateId="2">
                        <MatchDate startDateLocal="2011-02-11 19:40:00" dayName="Fri" shortDate="18-Feb">2011-02-11 19:40:00</MatchDate>
                        <Venue id="160" timeZoneID="AEDT" gmtMinutes="660" venue="AAMI Park" location="Melbourne">AAMI Park, Melbourne</Venue>
                        <HomeTeam id="76" alternateId="0">Rebels</HomeTeam>
                        <AwayTeam id="12" alternateId="422">Waratahs</AwayTeam>
                    </Match>
                    .. more matches
                </Competition>
                ... more competitions
            </Schedules>
        </Sport> 
    </Data>
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
I would have thought something along these line:

```
<cfset currentMatchNode = xmlSearch(thisScheduleXml,"/SportalData/Sport/Schedules/Match/MatchDate[@startLocalDate is current otherwise the next upcoming one]")>
```

Comment: Not possible to do with xpath alone because `XMLSearch()` doesn't support xpath date functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to match on date in XPath. Maybe someone else can help with that. However, in the past we've dealt with this in CF, using a loop. For example:

```
<cfset nodes = xmlSearch(x, "/Data/Sport/Schedules/Competition/Match") />
<cfset found = false />    

<cfloop array="#nodes#" index="match">

    <!--- Check to see if the match is on now or in the future --->
    <cfif match["MatchDate"].xmlText gte now()>
        <cfdump var="#match#" />
        <cfset found = true />
    </cfif>

    <!--- Only output the first --->
    <cfif found>
        <cfbreak />
    </cfif>

</cfloop>
```

That will print the `Match` node of the first match coming up. Hope it helps you in the right direction.

Comment: There are xpath date functions. The problem is that they are part of XPath 2.0, and it appears that ColdFusion (at least 8), only supports XPath 1.0.

This could be done in xpath with string parsing, but your problem is complicated by timezones. The cf code suggested here is probably the right approach, but will need to be modified to take into account the timezones.

http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp#datetime